# LTR and RTL <p> inline

Tags: html, right-to-left, paragraphs, left-to-right

I'm trying to fit two paragraphs (LTR and RTL) inline based on the image width. So both paragraphs are in the same line, but both reads from the opposite direction.
I tried to float: right the second paragraph (RTL) but it place it on top of the image.

HTML:

```
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p class="p-ltr">AGNAM RE VOLUPTAT LABO. ITAE PORATEM QUI SIN NUM FUGA.
ORPOREP TATUR, OMNIMOL ESSIMEN DANIMUST, OMMO EX EX EXCEATE
SUSTO ET VOLORIT ATEST, CONSECTEM CONE RESTI NIMI,
SED QUIA PRAESEQUUNT AUT ET VERCHICID ET ODI NONSEQUI
DERESTEM. PA CULPARI BEAQUI DELES ET ENDI DOLUPTAT IN REM
VOLO VOLORUMET AUT FACESTO EARUM CUS ULLECTAS CONSERUM
SUNDIT ANT, SOLEST AUTEM NOBITATUR ACIA VENIT LANT ODITEMAGNAM RE VOLUPTAT LABO. ITAE PORATEM QUI SIN NUM FUGA.
 </p> 
        <p class="p-rtl">AGNAM RE VOLUPTAT LABO. ITAE PORATEM QUI SIN NUM FUGA.
ORPOREP TATUR, OMNIMOL ESSIMEN DANIMUST, OMMO EX EX EXCEATE
SUSTO ET VOLORIT ATEST, CONSECTEM CONE RESTI NIMI,
SED QUIA PRAESEQUUNT AUT ET VERCHICID ET ODI NONSEQUI
DERESTEM. PA CULPARI BEAQUI DELES ET ENDI DOLUPTAT IN REM
VOLO VOLORUMET AUT FACESTO EARUM CUS ULLECTAS CONSERUM
SUNDIT ANT, SOLEST AUTEM NOBITATUR ACIA VENIT LANT ODITEMAGNAM RE VOLUPTAT LABO. ITAE PORATEM QUI SIN NUM FUGA..</p>
        <img src="images/intro_7.jpg" width="950" height="560">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
    z-index: -10;
}

#content img {
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#content img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#content h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 3vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#content p {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

#content .p-ltr {
    text-align: left;
    left: 25%;
    direction: ltr;
}

#content .p-rtl {
    text-align: right;
    /*left: 56.5%;*/
    direction: rtl;

}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RWmK2/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sending you the required code below, and check the [JS Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/CwNQL/) here.

This JS Fiddle has text alignment of LTR and RTL also.

I am now sending the [New JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/CwNQL/1/)

[image]

Here the width of content is fixed, and the distance between content and the images is also increased as needed.

```
#content {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
    z-index: -10;

}

#content img {
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#content img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#content h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 3vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#content p {
   /* position: relative;*/
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    width: 440px;
}

#content .p-ltr {
    direction: ltr;
    left: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}

#content .p-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

#content img {
    margin: 60px 0;
}
```

Regards D.

Comment: This works too, but I do have to use position: absolute; on #content. And have more space between the paragraphs so the match the width of the image.

Comment: If you want to make the text auto adjust to 50% width of the content wrapper, then you need to use bootstrap and then give required padding-left to the paragraph tag of .p-rtl and padding-right to .p-ltr classes.